# List of Thread and accessing another list

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, list

I've already made another question close to this one several minutes ago, and there were good answers, but it was not what I was looking for, so I tried to be a bit clearer.

Let's say I have a list of Thread in a class :

```
class Network {

    private List<Thread> tArray = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    private List<ObjectInputStream> input = new ArrayList<ObjectInputStream>();

    private void aMethod() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        String received = (String) input.get(****).readObject(); // I don't know what to put here instead of the ****
                        showReceived(received); // random method in Network class
                    } catch (IOException ioException) {
                        ioException.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            tArray.add(new Thread(r));
            tArray.get(i).start();
        }
    }
}
```

What should I put instead of **** ? 
The first thread of the tArray list must only access the first input of the input list for example.

EDIT : Let's assume my input list has already 10 elements

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616115/Java-Thread-Example#ai) would help you

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you put `i`. You also need to add an `ObjectInputStream` to the list for each thread. I recommend you use `input.add` for that purpose. You also need to fill the `tArray` list with some threads, use add again there.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wanted to assume the input list was already filed. But if I put i instead of the ****, it would not compile, since i would not exist when it would exit the loop, as opposed as the threads

Comment: That problem you talk about doesn't exist. `i` is passed to a compiler-generated constructor, and it should stick around in the inner class. What is the error message exactly?

Comment: Copy `i` into a `final` variable inside your loop and use that instead: `final int i2 = i;`

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: @damo This may be the good idea, but let's say I have to remove a thread for some reason (Let's say a client disconnected and I do tArray.remove(3), input.remove(3)), the problem is that for the 10th client, i2 will still have the same value, when in fact, it has to be decremented to 9, since the 10th client is now in the 9th position in the list

Comment: You should just create the `ObjectInputStream`s as final variables, then use them inside you inner class. Then you don't have to mess with lists and indices.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
private void aMethod() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int index = i;  // Captures the value of i in a final varialbe.
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String received = input.get(index).readObject().toString(); // Use te final variable to access the list.
                    showReceived(received); // random method in Network class
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        tArray.add(new Thread(r));
        tArray.get(i).start();
    }
}
```

As you want each thread to access one element from the input array you can use the value of the `i` variable as an index into the list. The problem with using `i` directly is that an inner class cannot access non-final variables from the enclosing scope. To overcome this we assign `i` to a final variable `index`. Being final `index` is accessible by the code of your `Runnable`.

Additional fixes:

- `readObject().toString()`
- `catch(Exception exception)`
- `tArray.add(new Thread(r))`

Comment: Woops, sorry about the errors. Unfortunateley, as I told damo, I cannot do such things, since if I have to remove a thread for some reason (Let's say a client disconnected and I do tArray.remove(3), input.remove(3)), the problem is that for the 10th client, index will still have the same value, when in fact, it has to be decremented to 9, since the 10th client is now in the 9th position of the list